# Updating a column value for multiple rows based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update, table-valued-parameters

I am trying to update a column for multiple rows. Following is my query

```
UPDATE [Members] 
SET [Credits]=[Credits]+@FreeCredits 
WHERE [ID] IN (SELECT T1.[MemberID] 
               FROM @Members T1 
               RIGHT JOIN [Members] T2 ON T1.MemberID!=T2.ID 
               WHERE T2.ActivePlan IS NULL)
```

What I am trying to do is that, I want to add free credits only to those members' accounts who don't have any active plan (=NULL). The list of members is in `@Members` table-valued parameter and `[Members]` is a table.

The query is not working as expected. It's adding credits to all the members, even to those who has `[ActivePlan]` not equal to `NULL`. Please tell me how to achieve this using one update query.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use right join. Just do inner join. Try like this,

```
UPDATE T2
SET [Credits] = [Credits] + @FreeCredits
FROM @Members T1
INNER JOIN [Members] T2 ON T1.MemberID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.ActivePlan IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks @StackUser I found the solution without using joins. Please have a look and tell me if it can fail in any test case.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, to bother you guys. Suddenly after posting my question the solution clicked in my mind. I tried following simple query and it worked :)

```
UPDATE [Members] SET [Credits]=[Credits]+@FreeCredits WHERE [ID] IN (SELECT [MemberID] FROM @Members) AND [ActivePlan] IS NULL
```

Please see if it has any problems. Thank you :)